# How to select children entities from a certain level in a self reference entity with JPA?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE DIVISIONS
(
    ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    NAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    ID_PARENT INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (ID_PARENT) REFERENCES DIVISIONS (ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

This entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DIVISIONS")
public class Division
{
    private int _id;
    private String _name;
    private Division _parent;
    private List<Division> _children = new ArrayList<>();

    public Division()
    {
    }

    public Division(String name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }

    public Division(String name, Division parent)
    {
        this(name);
        _parent = parent;
    }

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "DIVISIONS_ID_SEQ",
        sequenceName = "DIVISIONS_ID_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(
        strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "DIVISIONS_ID_SEQ")
    public int getId()
    {
        return _id;
    }

    public void setId(int id)
    {
        _id = id;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return _name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_PARENT")
    public Division getParent()
    {
        return _parent;
    }

    public void setParent(Division parent)
    {
        _parent = parent;
    }

    @OneToMany(
        mappedBy = "parent", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval = true)
    public List<Division> getChildren()
    {
        return _children;
    }

    public void setChildren(List<Division> children)
    {
        _children = children;
    }
}
```

and this sample code to insert some records in the database:

```
public class DivisionTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EntityManagerFactory emf =
            Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("test");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction transaction = em.getTransaction();
        transaction.begin();
        try
        {
            Division div1 = new Division("div1");

            Division div11 = new Division("div11", div1);
            Division div12 = new Division("div12", div1);
            Division div13 = new Division("div13", div1);

            Division div131 = new Division("div131", div13);
            Division div132 = new Division("div132", div13);
            div13.setChildren(Arrays.asList(div131, div132));

            Division div1321 = new Division("div1321", div132);
            div132.setChildren(Arrays.asList(div1321));

            Division div14 = new Division("div14", div1);
            div1.setChildren(Arrays.asList(div11, div12, div13, div14));

            Division div2 = new Division("div2");

            Division div3 = new Division("div3");
            Division div31 = new Division("div31", div3);
            Division div32 = new Division("div32", div3);
            div3.setChildren(Arrays.asList(div31, div32));

            em.persist(div1);
            em.persist(div2);
            em.persist(div3);

            transaction.commit();
        }
        finally
        {
            em.close();
            emf.close();
        }
    }
}
```

that will give me this structure:

```
div1
   div11
   div12
   div13
      div131
      div132
         div1321
   div14
div2
div3
   div31
   div32
```

Question: What JPQL query (or even a raw SQL query) would I use to select all children divisions of div1 (div11, div12, div13, div131, div132, div1321, div14) or from any other level (say for example, from div13)?

If that's not possible with the current table structure, what change would I do to my model to support this scenario?

Thank you.

Marcos

Comment: Why not grab div1 with a simple select by id and then iterate through until you get to desired div? Or do you want an actual JPQL query to only grab children based on parent ID?

Comment: You're exactly right. I want a JPQL or SQL query to do this. I wouldn't like to process the entity graph in code to achieve this. I know I can do this easily iterating through the children, but I wouldn't like to get it this way.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is`EclipseLink` library for `FetchGroup`

```
public Division findDivChildren(Integer id) {
   Division result = null;
   FetchGroup group = new FetchGroup("divChildren");

   group.addAttribute("_id");
   group.addAttribute("_children");

   Query q = em.createQuery("Select d from Division d where d.id = :id").setParameter("id", id);
   q.setHint(QueryHints.FETCH_GROUP, group);

   result = q.getSingleResult()

   return (result);
}
```

This will return the division specified by the id, with only the _id and _children field supplied. This will drastically reduce the sql log because it will not grab the _parent Division (which would then select all of its children + parents etc...)

Comment: Is this specific from EclipseLink? If so I can't use it because I use the Hibernate provider for JPA and also I don't want my code to depend on any provider proprietary features, even if it is from Hibernate. By the way I would prefer a query that would return to me the divisions flattened, without the need to iterate through them.

Comment: Maybe the answer is much simpler than you make it out to be... `Select d._children from Division d where d.id = :id` ?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, @j.con, but I can't use FetchGroup. I would like to find a solution using just standard JPA features.

Comment: Ok I understand... but my additional comment didn't help? `Select d._children from Division d where d.id = :id` that is standard JPA JPQL

Comment: I don't understand. How would your query select all divisions below a level? If I understand it well, if I pass to it, for example, the id belonging to 'div1', it will return only children div11, div12, div12 and div14, right? I also want it to return div131, div132 and div1321. If I want to get these aditional divisions I have to iterate through the first level divisions returned (div11, div12, div13, div14) using code. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Yes it will return div11, div12, div13, and div14... it will also return div131 and div132 UNDER div13... and div1321 UNDER div132... If you are trying to get just 1 result list containing all div's and their children at the same level... well that sounds pretty complicated

Comment: and that's what I want (however complicated it seems to be). I know that this is possible, I just don't know how. Maybe a change in my model (table and entity mapping) is needed, but I also don't know which change.